# Ferrite Beads - Maximum DC current and resistance

Tags: ferrite-bead

I'm building a PupDAC (http://www.diyforums.org/PupDAC) and am looking into two different Ferrite beads. The **plan for the PupDAC** calls for this Vishay/Dale model (**link 1**) while I'm looking into this Bourns model (**link 2**) which is cheaper. Both are the exact same size and have the same indapendance.

1. http://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Dale/ILB1206ER801V/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtoiMfofRG0LbeaUJjp%2fOFUt90sRTRBhVI%3d
2. http://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/MU3261-801Y/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMukHu%252bjC5l7YeIIR6MXfgmdW77QhVIYZMI%3d

The Vishay/Dale one has a maximum DC current of 200mA and a maximum DC resistance of 0.3 ohms. Meanwhile, the Bourns one has it at 300 mA and 0.6 Ohms respectively.

Basically, does this really matter? The Bourns models seems to just have higher maximum values, so can it replace the Vishay/Dale one without quality issues?

Comment: OK it's inductor A versus inductor B - what part of the DAC circuit are they used in? It's impossible (and plainly wrong) to compare two components without knowing what they are to be potentially used for.

Comment: Here's the schematic: http://www.diyforums.org/PupDAC/schematic/pupDACschematic.pdf

The ferrite beads are at locations L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, and L6.

Comment: It looks like a circuit but none of the IC devices have part numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The PupDAC schematics are terrible, and it is hard to know anything from them.  The R's and C's are not even correctly labeled (having to reference a BOM is not acceptable).  I honestly doubt that the people who designed the PupDAC did any detailed analysis of the beads.

Most of the beads are used on the output of a linear regulator.  I highly doubt that the beads are actually doing anything useful in that situation, and could actually be adding noise to the system.  I would remove L3, L4, L5, and L6.

As for L1 and L2, either the Vishay or Bournes will work.  I would probably go with the Bournes because of the higher current rating, but it has the disadvantage of the higher DC resistance.  In this application, the higher resistance isn't a huge disadvantage.

If you choose to not remove L3-6, either bead will work.  The Vishay would be slightly better because total current isn't as important but DC resistance is (for noise performance)  But you'd be better off with just a piece of wire instead of a bead.